# UIImage rotates when resizing only camera pictures, but works fine when screenshot pictures

Tags: ios, resize, uiimagepickercontroller

I have been using Trent's UIImage bundle to resize the image to fit my UIImage dimensions 320 * 320. When I use any picture from a screenshot or the web, vertical and horizontal are fine. But when I use a picture from an iPhone 5 camera, the vertical shot will rotate as though it were horizontal (a horizontal pic remains horizontal luckily). I have narrowed it down to when it happens in my code, and Trent's code makes sense, but I have no idea what could be causing just vertical camera pics to do this? Any ideas?

My code:

```
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        // Resizes the image, but unfortunately the below code also rotates it if vertical from an iPhone 5
UIImage *scaledImage = [image resizedImageWithContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill bounds:CGSizeMake(pic.frame.size.width, pic.frame.size.height) interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh];
```

Trent's code:

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImageWithContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode
                                  bounds:(CGSize)bounds
                    interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    CGFloat horizontalRatio = bounds.width / self.size.width;
    CGFloat verticalRatio = bounds.height / self.size.height;
    CGFloat ratio;

    switch (contentMode) {
        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
            ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
            break;

        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
            ratio = MIN(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio);
            break;

        default:
            [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"Unsupported content mode: %d", contentMode];
    }

    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width * ratio, self.size.height * ratio);

    return [self resizedImage:newSize interpolationQuality:quality];
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here is "resized image as well from Trent's code:

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    BOOL drawTransposed;
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    // In iOS 5 the image is already correctly rotated. See Eran Sandler's
    // addition here: http://eran.sandler.co.il/2011/11/07/uiimage-in-ios-5-orientation-and-resize/

    if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 5.0 ) 
    {
        drawTransposed = NO;  
    } 
    else 
    {    
        switch ( self.imageOrientation ) 
        {
            case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            case UIImageOrientationRight:
            case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
                drawTransposed = YES;
                break;
            default:
                drawTransposed = NO;
        }

        transform = [self transformForOrientation:newSize];
    } 

    return [self resizedImage:newSize transform:transform drawTransposed:drawTransposed interpolationQuality:quality];
}
```

AND here is the transform...but I already know that this is not where the actual problem lies:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)transformForOrientation:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:           // EXIF = 3
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:   // EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, newSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:           // EXIF = 6
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:   // EXIF = 5
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:          // EXIF = 8
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  // EXIF = 7
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, newSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:     // EXIF = 2
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:   // EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:   // EXIF = 5
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:  // EXIF = 7
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, newSize.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return transform;
}
```

Comment: Can we see `resizedImage::`

Comment: Alright. I have added that method as well. Also, I know that the picture is inserting into the frame properly

Comment: After scaling `UIImage` it is giving me wrong orientation ... Can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it

```
   - (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
        BOOL drawTransposed;
        switch ( self.imageOrientation )
        {
            case UIImageOrientationLeft:
                        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
                        case UIImageOrientationRight:
                        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
                      drawTransposed = YES;
                      break;
                        default:
                      drawTransposed = NO;
                }
        CGAffineTransform transform = [self transformForOrientation:newSize];

        return [self resizedImage:newSize transform:transform drawTransposed:drawTransposed interpolationQuality:quality];
    }
```

Comment: After scaling UIImage it is giving me wrong orientation ... Can you help ?